# Rewrite Values in Jetty 9.1.2

Tags: angular, deployment, routes, jetty, http-status-code-404

I have deployed my angular application on Jetty Server. My redirection of url is failing.
In angular I have used PathLocationStragey.

I am hitting the urls of my application
https://hostname/webdb/services/v5/search --> returning 404.

where my index.html has  `<base href="/webdb/">`

Similiar problem (Deep linking issue" is solved in Tomcat
following
http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/?unapproved=4436&moderation-hash=fba0216cc1cb22f2c0233872a06bc64d#comment-4436

But the rewrite configurations in jetty-rewrite.xml are not working

```
<Configure id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RuleContainer">
  <Call name="addRule">
<Arg>
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectPatternRule">
<Set name="pattern" type="String"></Set>         
<Set name="location">/webdb/index.html</Set>
</New>
</Arg>
</Call>


<Call name="addRule">
<Arg>
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectRegexRule">
<Set name="regex">(^(?!/webdb/).*)</Set>
<Set name="replacement">/webdb/</Set>
</New>
</Arg>
</Call>
</Configure>
```

**Can anyone suggest the correct rule for Jetty?**

Comment: Happy new year, how do you expect this to work?  Do you want to force all incoming requests to have `/webdb/` only path (breaking all requests for css, js, etc)? or do you only want 404 errors to redirect to `/webdb/` (not done with rewrite/redirect rules)?

Comment: Also, how is your angular application deployed in Jetty? (embedded? standalone? a raw directory of static resources? a war file? a webapp directory? a hybrid of any of the previous?).  What version of Jetty as well? (configuration is different across the 3 actively maintained major versions of Jetty atm)